# Statsmodels API: SARIMAX function missing

Tags: python, time-series, regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on time series analysis and have hit a hurdle early on. The "SARIMAX" library is unavailable using the following syntax, as per the statsmodels website:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX
```

I've also looked in e.g.:

```
sm.tsa.SARIMAX
```

Statespace is missing and so is SARIMAX in the other option. What am I doing wrong?

Using tab completion, I can't see any similar looking libraries (as a newbie to this field).

I'm using latest stable version: 0.6.1

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SARIMAX is not available in 0.6.1. You need to update to 0.8.0

Comment: So I ran a "conda install statsmodels" and also conda update but still 0.6.1. What I don't understand is why this website: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/documentation.html isn't integrated with this website: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels

Comment: new documentation is at http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html and development version at http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/index.html  There are no redirects yet on the sourceforge site

Comment: I see you've never accepted an answer before - if you find any of your questions to be resolved by one of the provided answers, you can mark that answer as "accepted" with the green checkmark on the left. It is appreciated so that others know your issue was resolved by that answer.

Comment: No one wrote an answer that was the answer. user333700 commented with the correct answer but I cannot see a way of accepting that as the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your import it should be:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```